# how to write a 3d text on a 3d model in XNA c#

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I need to write a text on top of 3d model on xna or on the model it self ?
I've made models for players and I need to show the name of each player either on it or on top of it !
thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could either use [Billboarding](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series2/Point_sprites.php) which draws the texture (or text) so that it always points at the camera, or you can make a new plane in your 3d modelling program, and position it where you want the text to appear on the player. Then texture it separately from the rest of the player and change the texture with `BasicEffect.Texture`

msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.basiceffect_members.aspx

I would definitely recommend billboarding over changing the texture, as it makes it a whole lot less complicated.